# Set the Focus on a particular DataGridView Cell when the Form loads

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have tried the following,

```
public INVOICE()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dgvInvoice.CurrentCell = dgvInvoice.Rows[0].Cells[2];
    dgvInvoice.BeginEdit(true);       
}
```

It only works when I am "clicking" the third cell (first row). I want that cell to be focused when the form load without any click.

Comment: Use current.focus

Comment: tried current.focus, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your code to `OnShown` method or `Shown` event. For example

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2];
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}
```